# Angular IF ELSE show element

Tags: angularjs

I am by setting the display type of a dashboard and came across this problem, how to make a if else in angular.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
<div ng-if="'CONFIG.dashboard.rows == 1'" layout="column" flex>
<div ng-if="'CONFIG.dashboard.rows > 1'" layout="row" flex>
```

---

RESOLVED:

```
<div ng-switch on="CONFIG.dashboard.rows" flex>

    <div ng-switch-when="1" layout="column" flex layout-wrap>

        <div ng-repeat="wdg in CONFIG.widgets" flex='100' ng-include="wdg.template"></div>

    </div>


    <div ng-switch-default layout="row" flex layout-wrap>

        <div ng-repeat="wdg in CONFIG.widgets" flex='50' ng-include="wdg.template"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you have a look at angular views? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Comment: I just want to put an element or change it, depending on the settings made.

With views I would have a lot more work, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: what is the actual problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If else conditions in angularjs templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315963/if-else-conditions-in-angularjs-templates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) directive to accomplish this.

Comment: I can use on one line?